# BackboneJS - How to create Model and/or Collection from JSON file

Tags: json, backbone.js

I have a JSON file which I need to display on my Backbone App by using `HandlebarsJS` but I'm not really sure how to achieve this.

Here is the structure of my JSON file:

```
data: {title:Win special things, startDate:null, endDate:2014-08-04T10:00:00.000Z,privacy:public,…}
  contest_id: 11
  endDate: "2014-08-04T10:00:00.000Z"
  privacy: "public"
  question: {title:When was "The Black Album" released?, question_id:11,…}
     answers: [{answer_id:16, answer:1992, correct:false, createdAt:2014-06-23T08:09:17.000Z,…},…]
           0: {answer_id:16, answer:1992, correct:false, createdAt:2014-06-23T08:09:17.000Z,…}
           1: {answer_id:17, answer:1993, correct:false, createdAt:2014-06-23T08:09:17.000Z,…}
           2: {answer_id:18, answer:1991, correct:true, createdAt:2014-06-23T08:09:17.000Z,…}
           3: {answer_id:19, answer:1990, correct:false, createdAt:2014-06-23T08:09:17.000Z,…}
              answer: "1990"
              answer_id: 19
              contest_questionId: 11
              correct: false
              createdAt: "2014-06-23T08:09:17.000Z"
              updatedAt: "2014-06-23T08:09:17.000Z"
      question_id: 11
      title: "When was "The Black Album" released?"
  startDate: null
  status: "editing"
  title: "Win special things"
```

I tried to do this:

```
SingleCompetition.SingleCompetitionCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: function() {
        return App.APIO + '/i/contest/' + 11;  // *('11' is the id of the contest)*
    }
});
```

but when I console.log the collection after `singleCompetitionCollection.fetch()` - it tells me `undefined` and it returns nothing.

How can I do it?

**UPDATE**

Ok, changed into :

```
SingleCompetition.SingleCompetitionModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: function() {
        return App.APIO + '/i/contests';
    },

    defaults: {
        "data": []
    }
});
```

and my HandlebarsJS HTML looks like (just a bit of it, just as example):

```
 {{#each this}}
  <li>
     <h2>{{title}}</h2>
 </li>  
{{/each}}
```

It shows the `<h2>` empty. Console tells me that data JSON is available, so I'm close I think, what could be issue?

Comment: 1) json is not valid 2) collection SingleCompetitionCollection has no model 3) no competition model 4) need parse function to handle such json

Comment: OK, JSON was actually valid :-) and added Model now, please check updated code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself by simply doing this:

```
{{#each data}}
<li>
  <h2>{{title}}</h2>
</li>  
{{/each}}
```

Now it displays what I want!

Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SingleCompetition.SingleCompetitionCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: SingleCompetition.SingleCompetitionModel,
            url: json_url_here,

            initialize: function() {
                this.fetch({ type:"GET" }).error(function(){
                    console.error("error");
                });
            }
        });
```